# Writing or Copying File To Network Share in C#

Tags: c#, file, networking, printing, io

I've written a Windows Service that impersonates session 0 to access local printers and prints money orders to networked dot-matrix printers. That part works great, and the idea is that the client terminals (running 3.5 desktop app) will generate an xml file that is written to (or copied, I don't care) to a share on that machine, and the Print Queue Service will pick these up every few seconds, order them by number and store, and send the job to the correct store's printer. That all works.

However our issue is that we can't save the xml files to the remote share without first saving credentials on every single computer. Despite sharing it with EVERYONE having read/write/modify access to the share, it won't work. Obviously the client is unwilling to type in a username and password for 300+ computers.

I've tried everything I can think of. I've tried impersonation using WindowsIdentity and WindowsImpersonationContext, but I always get "The name provided is not a properly formed account name." no matter if I use name@domain or domain\name, or the application quits with no error messages logged in the event viewer or our database. I've tried using the code found [here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/windowsservices/article.php/c12357/C-Map-Network-Drive-API.htm) which maps the drive successfully but I am denied access to it. I've tried alternative code to use LogonUser from the Windows API (doesn't work). I've shared and re-shared the folder with the least restrictive permissions I can find. Nothing works.

Any suggestions on what we can do at this point? The code is here:

```
 foreach (MoneyOrderPrinterLineItem item in this.Lines)
        {
            string path = Globals.MoneyOrderPrintJobsPath + Globals.Store.StoreNameID.ToString("0#") +
                (Globals.DrawerContext.GetActiveDrawer()?.DrawerNameOnly) + Security.UserName + item.Number +
                DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy") + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss") + ".xml";

            try
            {
                XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                settings.Indent = true;
                settings.Encoding = ASCIIEncoding.Unicode;


                //create a new file for each money order
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.CreateNew))
                {
                    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartDocument();
                        writer.WriteStartElement("PrintJob");

                        writer.WriteStartElement("Source");
                        writer.WriteElementString("Name", Security.UserName);
                        writer.WriteElementString("Store", Globals.Store.StoreNameID.ToString("0#"));
                        writer.WriteElementString("StoreID", Globals.Store.ID.ToString());
                        writer.WriteElementString("Drawer", Globals.DrawerContext.GetActiveDrawer()?.DrawerNameOnly);
                        writer.WriteElementString("DateTime", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
                        writer.WriteElementString("Machine", Environment.MachineName);
                        writer.WriteElementString("PrinterName", Globals.Store.MoneyOrderPrinter);
                        writer.WriteEndElement();

                        writer.WriteStartElement("Details");
                        writer.WriteElementString("Number", item.Number);
                        writer.WriteElementString("Payee", item.Payee);
                        writer.WriteElementString("Remitter", item.Remitter);
                        writer.WriteElementString("AmountDesc", item.AmountText);
                        writer.WriteElementString("Amount", item.Amount.ToString("F2"));
                        writer.WriteElementString("Fee", item.Fee.ToString("F2"));
                        writer.WriteElementString("BusinessDate", item.Date);
                        writer.WriteElementString("Notes", item.StoreNotes);
                        writer.WriteEndElement();

                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        writer.WriteEndDocument();
                        writer.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ioEX)
            {
                Methods.ProcessException(ioEX, true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Methods.ProcessException(ex, true);
            }
        }
```

All of the machines are on the same domain. The global money order path is `\\WEB2012R2-DEV\MOPrints`

Comment: Client-server approach?  Run a server on the printing machine, have clients send jobs using HTTP?

Comment: Dave S, that's a great idea. In fact, there is already a 2.0 ASP.NET webservice that runs on that machine, allowing interaction with 3rd party services. I can just add another method to that - send it the xml and it will write the file the print queue service will pick up.

Comment: Make a web service that accepts the files to print instead of relying on a network share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion to use our web service to save the files locally worked beautifully. Thanks everyone!